# Xamarin.Form how do i get the ios project from PC to Mac?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

form project on my PC
and i have my mac paired.
[image]

But i cant figure out how i get the ios project to my mac so i can make a IOS file that i can upload to appstore. Dont need help upload the app. Just to get it over to mac so i can make the file.

Have search for answered but nothing helpes

thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uploded the project to dropbox and then downloaded it on my mac. Easy way out

Answer (score 0):

When you do everything right, you should be able to click on that "IPA" icon and you'll see the file on the Mac.

But before that you've got a lot to learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows

Comment: The IPA is gray.

Comment: I clearly said 'you've got a lot to learn' and gave you the link. No one will read that text for you. When you do things from the text it won't be gray anymore.

Comment: I added more text but site say cant eddit more then onece 5 min. 
I have Done the steps, i im stuck on one step thats Provisioning profile. I have been on the  on options->xamarin>apple account and when i press download al profiles there is none.

Comment: Either they are not install on the mac or they don't match the app. You may try to restart VS just in case.